# Can you apply Hoeffding's inequality for the mean of Normal variates?

Tags: probability

Suppose $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ are i.i.d. from $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. How can we prove a concentration inequality of the mean such that for $\epsilon>0$:

$$
P(|\bar{Y} - \mu| \geq \epsilon) \leq 2\exp{-n\epsilon^2/(2\sigma^2)}
$$

Hoeffding's inequality states that for $|Y_j|\leq c$, we have

$$
P(|\bar{Y} - \mu| \geq \epsilon) \leq 2\exp{-n\epsilon^2/(2c^2)}
$$

Can it be directly applied here?

Comment: There's a more general version of Hoeffding's inequality for sub-gaussian random variables (see Vershynin's book).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that if $X\sim\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$, you have the following tail bound
$$\mathbb P(|X|>t)\le2\exp\left(\frac{-t^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\tag1 $$
Which is a consequence of the well-known [Chernoff bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound) and can be proven as follows :
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(|X|>t)=2\mathbb P(X>t)&\le 2 \inf_{s>0}\frac{\mathbb E[e^{sX}]}{e^{st}}\\
&\le2 \inf_{s>0}\exp\left(\frac{s^2\sigma^2}{2} -st\right)\\
&=2\exp\left(\frac{-t^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\end{align*} $$
Now, if all the $Y_i$ are independent and $\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$-distributed, then $\bar Y-\mu\sim\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2/n)$. So applying the tail bound $(1)$ to $\bar Y-\mu$ yields
$$\mathbb P(|\bar Y -\mu|>t)\le2\exp\left(\frac{-nt^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) $$
As desired.

Comment: May I ask how you got the $2P(X>t)\le 2 \inf_{s>0}\frac{E[e^{sX}]}{e^{st}}$ relation in the first line? Thank you

Comment: It's the Chernoff bound I linked to. To prove it, just notice that for all $s>0$
$$\mathbb P(X>t) = \mathbb P(sX>st) = \mathbb P(e^{sX}>e^{st})$$
Then by Markov's inequality it follows that
$$\mathbb P(X>t) \le \frac{\mathbb E[e^{sX}]}{e^{st}} $$
and because the inequality holds for all $s>0$, you can take the infimum.